# How to send post request with only 1 argument in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-httpclient

I'm using Angular6, HttpClient, this is logout

```
logout() {
    return this.http.post(this.logout_url);
}
```

And the error is

> Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.

It's expecting the header or data, but I don't have any data to post, if I add a header, the error is fixed, and everything will work but I don't want to do that, since I have angular HTTP interceptor, and the job of the interceptor is to add a header to any request automatically. So no need to write the same code twice.

So how to send post request with only one argument?

Comment: Stupid question: is it possible to provide an empty Header as workaround?

Comment: Just pass `null` to the other two arguments

Comment: @kboul null works, could you please post it as an answer just so I could close the question

Comment: Keep in mind you need to subscribe

Comment: @Oram Good point thank you for remind me.

Comment: What kind of POST request is it when you don't need body at all?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović if I send a post request with the header that contains the `x-session` I can logout, and the `x-session` is added automatically to the header by angular http interceptor, I don't need to write it again in logout method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass `null` to the other arguments like this:

```
logout() {
   return this.http.post(this.logout_url, null, null);
}
```